# How to convert xy coordinates to longitude and latitude in mysql or SQL Server

Tags: sql, spatial, spatial-query

I have a point geometry with Oracle in x, y coordinates

```
"MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY"(2001,2400000,"MDSYS"."SDO_POINT_TYPE"(8452842.1981,4443992.9047,NULL),NULL,NULL)
```

and same geometry with longitude and latitude

```
SELECT SDO_CS.TRANSFORM("MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY"(2001,2400000,"MDSYS"."SDO_POINT_TYPE"(8452842.1981,4443992.9047,NULL),NULL,NULL), 4326) FROM DUAL
```

Result is

```
"MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY"(2001,4326,"MDSYS"."SDO_POINT_TYPE"(44.4467355804591,40.1282575487861,NULL),NULL,NULL)
```

How I can convert same x, y coordinates 8452842.1981,4443992.9047 to longitude and latitude with MySQL or SQL Server?

```
PROJCS["Armenia GK-8 (ARM-DAT)", 
GEOGCS [ "ARM-Geodetic", 
DATUM ["ARM-DAT (EPSG ID 2400001)", 
SPHEROID ["Krassowsky 1940 (EPSG ID 7024)", 6378245.0, 298.3], 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], 
PRIMEM [ "Greenwich", 0.000000 ], 
UNIT ["Decimal Degree", 0.0174532925199433]], 
PROJECTION ["Transverse Mercator"], 
PARAMETER ["Latitude_Of_Origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER ["Central_Meridian", 45.0], 
PARAMETER ["Scale_Factor", 1.0], 
PARAMETER ["False_Easting", 8500000.0], 
PARAMETER ["False_Northing", 0.0], 
UNIT ["Meter", 1.0]]
```

Comment: You really should use a search engine to find basic stuff like this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Please chose a (R)DBMS; MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products ,and you've also tagged Oracle, just to confuse matters more.

Comment: I want solutions or MySQL or SQL Server, I have both RDBMS